# Optimal coalition structure

Tags: python, algorithm, math, logic

The problem is the following: if there is a set `S = {x1, ..., x_n}` and a function `f`: set -> number, which takes a set as an input and returns a number as an output, what is the best possible coalition structure (coalition structure a set of subsets of a `S`.That is, find the subsets,such that the sum of `f(s_i)` for every subset `s_i` in `S` is maximal). The sets in the coalition should not overlap and their union should be `S`.
A template is this:

```
def optimal_coalition(coalitions):
    """
    :param coalitions: a dictionary of the form {coalition: value}, where coalition is a set, and value is a number
    :return:
    """


optimal_coalition({set(1): 30, set(2): 40, set(1, 2): 71}) # Should return set(set(1, 2))
```

This is from a paper I found:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I transliterated the pseudocode. No doubt you can make it better -- I was hewing very closely to show the connection.

I did fix a bug (`Val(C') + Val(C \ C') > v(C)` should be `Val(C') + Val(C \ C') > Val(C)`, or else we may overwrite the best partition with one merely better than all of `C`) and two typos (`C / C'` should be `C \ C'`; and `CS*` is a set, not a tree).

```
import itertools


def every_possible_split(c):
    for i in range(1, len(c) // 2 + 1):
        yield from map(frozenset, itertools.combinations(tuple(c), i))


def optimal_coalition(v):
    a = frozenset(x for c in v for x in c)
    val = {}
    part = {}
    for i in range(1, len(a) + 1):
        for c in map(frozenset, itertools.combinations(tuple(a), i)):
            val[c] = v.get(c, 0)
            part[c] = {c}
            for c_prime in every_possible_split(c):
                if val[c_prime] + val[c - c_prime] > val[c]:
                    val[c] = val[c_prime] + val[c - c_prime]
                    part[c] = {c_prime, c - c_prime}
    cs_star = {a}
    while True:
        for c in cs_star:
            if part[c] != {c}:
                cs_star.remove(c)
                cs_star.update(part[c])
                break
        else:
            break
    return cs_star


print(
    optimal_coalition({frozenset({1}): 30, frozenset({2}): 40, frozenset({1, 2}): 69})
)
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for implementing the pseudocode! I need it for small examples anyways, so no need for performance here. Have a great day!!! :)